# Doing SQL with python and can't connect to localhost or 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, localhost

I am absolute beginner with programming in general. I've tried to create a sql database.
Unfortunately this part of my code always returns an error:

```
import mysql.connector
MainDatabase = mysql.connector.connect(
    host ="127.0.0.1",
    user ="Username",
    password ="Idon'tknowE"
```

The error being:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/My Name/xx/Program/Scripts/test.py", line xx, in <module>
    database="mydatabase"
  File "/Users/My Name/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/My Name/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/My Name/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/Users/My Name/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/Users/My Name/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 512, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (61 Connection refused)
```

I am running this on mac and more specifically Catalina. Anyone have an idea of what's going on or how to fix this?

Comment: Question 1: Did you start the MySQL Server instance? Or maybe we better start with Do you have a MySQL Server instance installed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a separate application from python, that is supposed to run at the same time as your application. The code you wrote then connects you to it.

Since MySQL is not running on your computer your code cannot work. Either that or MySQL is running, but not at the adress you specified

You can start here to install it:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/installing.html

You will then need to setup a user with credentials that you'll use in your code, and then you need to ensure you are using the correct adress for where mysql is running.